# mod_rewrite setting with .htaccess for Slim Framework on OpenShift

Tags: openshift, slim

I am trying to setup Slim Framework on OpenShift.

According to this [link](https://github.com/codeguy/Slim), I have to have an .htaccess file like below in the same directory of the index.php:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

However, things seems to work a bit different on OpenShift, I ended up with the following .htaccess for OpenShift by referring to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24724527/rewriterule-apache-directives-in-htaccess-not-working):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

It sure looks fine for me, but when I try to access the end point, PHP just returned me a 404. The default welcome index.php generated by OpenShift works fine though.

Appreciate if anyone can point me out where my mistake was. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.